# CSS: make <button> and <a> look identical

Tags: css

I'm making a button component for Svelte, and it outputs either a `<button>` element or an `<a>`, depending on if you give it an `href` or not. Everything basically works perfect, the buttons and the links all look the same in the different styles.. except for my round button style:

[image]

That last row is all `<a>` tags. REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/756e88bc3a8f4150872f6af66a4a7e4a?version=3.50.1.

How can I get the buttons and links to look the same? Why the they even behave so extremely different?

```css
:root {
  --primary-hsl: 135deg 62% 48%;
  --primary: hsl(var(--primary-hsl));
  --s2: 0.5rem;
  --s4: 1rem;
}
    
  .btn {
    background: none;
    padding: var(--s2) var(--s4);
    border-radius: var(--s2);
    color: var(--primary);
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }

  .btn:hover {
    background: hsl(var(--primary-hsl) / 0.2);
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .round {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    background: hsl(var(--primary-hsl) / 0.1);
  }

  .outline {
    border: 1px solid var(--primary);
  }

  .filled {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)) var(--primary);
    color: white;
  }

  .filled:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)) var(--primary);
  }

  .disabled,
  .disabled:hover {
    color: #888;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    background: transparent;
  }

  .disabled.outline,
  .disabled.outline:hover {
    border-color: #888;
  }

  .disabled.filled,
  .disabled.filled:hover {
    background: #d7d7d7;
    color: #888;
  }
```

```html
<p><button type="button" class="btn svelte-1l0536l">Default</button> <button type="button" class="btn outline svelte-1l0536l">Outlined</button> <button type="button" class="btn filled svelte-1l0536l">filled</button> <button type="button" class="btn round svelte-1l0536l">i</button></p> <p><button type="button" class="btn disabled svelte-1l0536l" disabled="">Default</button> <button type="button" class="btn outline disabled svelte-1l0536l" disabled="">Outlined</button> <button type="button" class="btn filled disabled svelte-1l0536l" disabled="">filled</button> <button type="button" class="btn round disabled svelte-1l0536l" disabled="">i</button></p> <p><a href="#" class="btn svelte-1l0536l" role="button" rel="noreferrer noopener">Default</a> <a href="#" class="btn outline svelte-1l0536l" role="button" rel="noreferrer noopener">Outlined</a> <a href="#" class="btn filled svelte-1l0536l" role="button" rel="noreferrer noopener">filled</a> <a href="#" class="btn round svelte-1l0536l" role="button" rel="noreferrer noopener">i</a></p>
```

Comment: Do they have `display: inline-block`?

Comment: Yes, they do indeed

Comment: How about some CSS and HTML? See [ask] and this section on [mcve] and [how make a Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: There is a link to a REPL with all the html and css you could want

Comment: I also created a code snippet here, although the Svelte REPL is probably a lot easier to work with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding some flex rules for alignment to the `.round` class could solve it:

```css
display: inline-flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-hsl: 135deg 62% 48%;
  --primary: hsl(var(--primary-hsl));
  --s2: 0.5rem;
  --s4: 1rem;
}

.btn {
  background: none;
  padding: var(--s2) var(--s4);
  border-radius: var(--s2);
  color: var(--primary);
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: hsl(var(--primary-hsl) / 0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.round {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  background: hsl(var(--primary-hsl) / 0.1);
  
  /**********************************/  
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /**********************************/  

}

.outline {
  border: 1px solid var(--primary);
}

.filled {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)) var(--primary);
  color: white;
}

.filled:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)) var(--primary);
}

.disabled,
.disabled:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background: transparent;
}

.disabled.outline,
.disabled.outline:hover {
  border-color: #888;
}

.disabled.filled,
.disabled.filled:hover {
  background: #d7d7d7;
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button type="button" class="btn svelte-1l0536l">Default</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn outline svelte-1l0536l">Outlined</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn filled svelte-1l0536l">filled</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn round svelte-1l0536l">i</button>
</p>

<p>
  <button type="button" class="btn disabled svelte-1l0536l" disabled="">Default</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn outline disabled svelte-1l0536l" disabled="">Outlined</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn filled disabled svelte-1l0536l" disabled="">filled</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn round disabled svelte-1l0536l" disabled="">i</button>
</p>

<p>
  <a href="#" class="btn svelte-1l0536l" role="button" rel="noreferrer noopener">Default</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn outline svelte-1l0536l" role="button" rel="noreferrer noopener">Outlined</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn filled svelte-1l0536l" role="button" rel="noreferrer noopener">filled</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn round svelte-1l0536l" role="button" rel="noreferrer noopener">i</a>
 </p>
```

Comment: Would there be an argument not to change the `.btn { display: inline-block }` to `-flex` instead of adding it to `.round`?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about `display: inline-flex`! I did play around with `display: flex` but that was putting the button on its own line of course 

Comment: I'm still curious why this is needed for the link and not for the button. What is their fundamental difference?

Comment: @Corrl You could almost certainly put it somewhere further up, and there are strong arguments for doing that. I was being a bit lazy and going for the simplest demonstrable fix.

Comment: @KevinRenskers Buttons have default styles that anchors don’t have. Anchors are `display: inline` by default, for example, so    padding and margins behave differently, you can’t  set their height,  etc.